# Wrong count result in mysql when joining two tables

Tags: mysql

I am trying to join two tables and get the count and grouped by specific field. However, it outputs same count values even if the other table consist only two rows. How should I fix this?

Here's my code:

```
SELECT tbl1.preferredDay, COUNT(tbl1.preferredDay) as count_1, COUNT(tbl2.preferredDay) as count_2 
FROM tblschedule as tbl1 
LEFT JOIN tblappointments as tbl2 ON (tbl1.preferredDay = tbl2.preferredDay) 
WHERE tbl1.preferredDay = tbl2.preferredDay 
GROUP BY preferredDay;
```

Here is the output but it should be [15, 0][3, 3]

Comment: Can you share some input data and the expected output

Answer (score 0):

Your query is based on `left join` it will return the same count().

This is a working query for `Mysql 8`:

```
with tbl1 as (
  SELECT preferredDay, count(1) as count_1
  FROM tblschedule
  GROUP BY preferredDay
),
tbl2 as (
  SELECT preferredDay, count(1) as count_2
  FROM tblappointments
  GROUP BY preferredDay
)
select t1.preferredDay, t1.count_1, t2.count_2
from tbl1 t1
inner join tbl2 t2 on t1.preferredDay = t2.preferredDay
```

There are two `WITH`s to get separately the count and then an `INNER JOIN` to join those results

For Mysql 5.7 and lower :

```
select t1.preferredDay, t1.count_1, t2.count_2
from (
  SELECT preferredDay, count(1) as count_1
  FROM tblschedule
  GROUP BY preferredDay
) as t1
inner join (
  SELECT preferredDay, count(1) as count_2
  FROM tblappointments
  GROUP BY preferredDay
) as t2 on t1.preferredDay = t2.preferredDay
```